React Material UI Autocomplete
When I am using autocomplete its not showing the correct list of items in the suggested dropdown its showing values that matches my value and other values also some specific string. For example, if I type "Lokesh" its suggests lokesh and neel, gulshan also in the suggestion.

      <Autocomplete
      className={classes.searchUser}
        options={usersList?.users?.map((user: any) => user.display_name)}
        onChange={(event: any, newValue: any) => {
          setSearchValue(newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={(params: any) => (
          <TextField {...params} placeholder="Select User" />
        )}

        value={searchValue}
        sx={{ width: 300, borderColor: "red" }}
      />


Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.
